# Using radio buttons to show approved or unapproved users in admin panel in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, switch-statement

I have a project wherein I need to show unapproved and approved user from the database. I have to show it by radio buttons such as All, Approved and Unapproved. I want to know how to list each of them ,as the radio choice is clicked, on the same page. I am a fresher in PHP and its my first project and so highly confused.

I am trying to put in switch for radio and no idea about how to write MySQL query in each switch case. Is there any solution or code  available? Is there any way to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; ?>
<?php
$errmsg         =   "" ;
$module_id      =   '';
$query          =   '';

$date_from      =   '';

$date_to        =   '';





//Search section start here

$sqlQuery       =   "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 " ;

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

{ 

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['date_from']))

    {

        $date_from      =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['date_from'])) ;  

    }

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['date_to']))

    {

        $date_to        =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['date_to'])) ;    

    }

    if(!empty($date_to) && empty($date_from))
{

        $errmsg =   "Please select valid date range.";

}

    if(!empty($date_to) && (strtotime($date_from)> strtotime($date_to)))

    {

        $errmsg =   "Please select valid date range.";

    }



    if($errmsg =='')

    {

    if(!empty($date_to) && (strtotime($date_from)<= strtotime($date_to)))

    {
        $sqlQuery       .=  " AND created_on BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'";      
    }
    $sqlQuery       .= "  order by id DESC";
    }
$date_from  = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($date_from));
$date_to    = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($date_to));
$date_from  =    $date_from != '01/01/1970' ? $date_from : '';
$date_to    =    $date_to != '01/01/1970' ? $date_to : '';
}
?>
<div class="container pagecontainer">

  <!-- Static navbar -->

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">

      <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
 <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>
    </div>
      </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">

        <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">Search Registered Candidate</div>

        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">

                <?php

                if($errmsg!="")

                {

                    echo "<div class='error'>".ucwords($errmsg)."</div>";

                }

                ?>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="">



              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-md-6">

                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Date From:</label>

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="input-group date">

                      <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Dob must be a date." data-val-required="The Dob field is required." id="Dob" name="date_from" placeholder="Date From" type="text" value="<?php echo $date_from ; ?>" >

                      </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Date To:</label>

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="input-group date">

                      <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Dob must be a date." data-val-required="The Dob field is required." id="Dob" name="date_to" placeholder="Date To" type="text" value="<?php echo $date_to ; ?>" >

                     </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-md-6">



                  <div class="col-md-8 text-left">

                   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Search</button>

                    <button type="reset" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='reportRegisteredUsers.php'" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <label for="username" class="control-label"> </label>

                  </div>



                  <div class="col-md-8 text-right">



                  </div>





                </div>

              </div>

            </form>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">Report:Candidate Reports</div>



        <div class="panel-body">

           <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked"> All Candidates<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Approved Candidates<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Unapproved Candidates<br>         

          <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">

            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%">

              <thead>

                <tr>

                  <th>S.No.</th>

                  <th>Email ID</th>

                  <th>SBI Employee ID</th>

                  <th>Name</th>

                  <th>Mobile No.</th>

                  <th>Date of Birth</th>

                  <th>Registration Date</th>



                </tr>

              </thead>

              <tbody>

<?php



$sq             =   $db->query($sqlQuery);

$i              =   1 ;

if($db->affected_rows > 0)

{

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))

    {

     extract($row);

?>              

                <tr>

                  <td><?php echo $i ; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $email ; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $employee_id ; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $first_name."&nbsp;".$middle_name."&nbsp;".$last_name ; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $mobile ; ?></td>

                  <td><?php if($dob !='1970-01-01'){echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dob)) ; }?></td>

                  <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on)) ; ?></td>

                </tr>

<?php $i++;}} ?>              



               </tbody>

            </table>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

  <div> <button type="reset" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Go Back</button>  </div>     

      <!--/row-->

    </div>

    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->

  </div>

</div>

<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php'
```

Comment: Clean out the empty lines, they look very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a very very simple page for what you want to archive.

```
<?php 
//connection with database here.

if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'approved'){
    $sql = "your query";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);

    while($row = result->fetch_assoc()){
        $users[] = $row;
    }

}elseif(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'unapproved'){
    $sql = "your query";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);

    while($row = result->fetch_assoc()){
        $users[] = $row;
    }

}elseif(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'other'){
    $sql = "your query";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);

    while($row = result->fetch_assoc()){
        $users[] = $row;
    }

}


?>


<div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Approved<input type="radio" name="users" value="approved">
        Unapproved<input type="radio" name="users" value="unapproved">
        Other<input type="radio" name="users" value="other">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="results">
    <?php foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    ?>
        <div class="user">
            <div><?php echo $value['firstName']; ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $value['lastName']; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx mate for being there but I have one single page ... I don't have any other page for approved and unapproved. So in that case?

Comment: You can't do this in only one page at least if you want to use jquery ajax you need another page where you can make requests. Is there any reason why you are using only one page ?

Comment: well no specific reason but I wanted to handle this only by php and MySQL. Going for jquery and ajax may take time as I am completely new to it.

Comment: But with radio button you would need to refresh te page. So it's simple just create a form with only radio button on it and a button to submit the form. If value of $_POST['nameOfRadioButton'] == 'approved' show approved users

Comment: Yup that's a possibility for me. Thank you so much. And can I know where and how to place my MySQL queries. I mean there will be three for three radios

Comment: I will edit my answer so it will be for your problem now so you can accept it later :)

Comment: thereare errors mate. its not executing.           foreach ($users as $key => $value) {.. the foreach is throwing an syntax error

Comment: It's because your queries are not ok and $users is empty maybe. I cannot know what are you doing wrong but you wanted a way how to do it and here you have

Comment: yes. I am still stuck at it. Can you make the executable code for this. Sorry to ask you for that but I have tried a lot and there is no success. too frustrating it is @edisoni.1337

Comment: This code is executable @anand you just need to add queries there

Comment: Thanks mate. Its done. Great help.. Plus 1 for you !!